# MySQL and PHP: Getting a SUM from a row in column A based on a DATE from column A joined by an ID in column B?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So, as the title says, I think I want to get the SUM of a row in column A (Meta Value) based on matching DATEs in column A (Meta Value) joined from IDs in column B (Item ID).

Essentially, I want to look for a specific date `2017-05-05` in Meta Value. Then, when a date is a match, find the `Item ID`. In the example below, this would be 2 and 3. Then, get the `SUM` of the `Field ID (11)` for both `Item ID 2` and `Item ID 3` and return the `SUM` to a variable in PHP.

Here is what my data looks like:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| Meta Value|  Field ID  | Item ID    | 
+-----------+------------+------------+
|   John    |     8      |     1      |
|john@e.com |    10      |     1      |
|    2      |    11      |     1      |
|2016-11-20 |    12      |     1      |
|   Mary    |     8      |     2      |
|mary@e.com |    10      |     2      |
|   **5**   |    11      |     2      |
|2017-05-05 |    12      |     2      |
|   Mike    |     8      |     3      |
|mike@e.com |    10      |     3      |
|   **2**   |    11      |     3      |
|2017-05-05 |    12      |     3      |
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

I am after the SUM of 7 from Mike and Mary.

My current wordpress php call looks like this (but only gets me row count):

```
$bookings    = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id=12 AND meta_value='$select_date'");
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server. Pick one.

Comment: I choose you MySQL!

Comment: Your  sample is not related  to your explanation  .. where are  columns A; B  ..join  ,, ???? try explain better  .,.

Comment: @scaisEdge Updated explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you need  sum on a self join

```
  select sum(a.field_id)
  from  wp_frm_item_metas a
  inner join wp_frm_item_metas b on b.item_id = a.item_id 
            and b.meta_value = '$select_date'
```

but if you need  the sum for meta_value (11) you should

```
  select sum(a.meta_vale)
  from  wp_frm_item_metas a
  inner join wp_frm_item_metas b on b.item_id = a.item_id 
            and b.meta_value = '$select_date' 
            and a.filed_id =11
```

Comment: I'm assuming this isn't right: `$bookings = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT SUM(field_id) FROM wp_frm_item_metas a INNER JOIN wp_frm_item_metas b ON b.item_id = a.item_id AND b.meta_value ='$select_date'");`

Comment: When using with the database I get this error: `#1052 - Column 'field_id' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: Hey, okay, that error is gone. The only issue now is, the number returned is way higher than it should be. I get a value of around 451 and it should be like 40... I reviewed the data and all the entries are good. It seems like it is adding all the data together...

Comment: You have several row for item_id 2 and 3  and these are summed ..in your data sample the result should be 82

Comment: Oh, I think I have explained wrong. I am looking to get a sum of 7 from the `meta_value` field by adding together `field_id = 11` for both `item_id = 2` and `item_id = 3` because both of their `field_id = 12` is `2017-05-05`

Comment: My previous comment may be more confusing, so I'll add: I'm trying to get 7 from the 2 and 5 from `meta_value` column because they have the same date...

Comment: so you don't want the sum of field_id but the sum of meta_value (5+2) ..?  . please confirm

Comment: great job! Not sure how you are with javaScript, but I have this question still unanswered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48175760/javascript-how-to-handle-proper-time-with-audio-context